# List index error (out of range) does not make sense in python

Tags: list, indexing

So I am trying to separate a text file using line.split() and a for loop, but I am getting an index error. I have read around and understand why this error is given but I don't understand how index[0] and index[1] could be out of range (I bolded the line that is returning the error):

`names = {}`
`file = open('sourcefile.txt', 'r')`
`text += file.readlines()`
`file.close()`
`for line in text:`
    `tmp = line.split()`
    `**names[tmp[1]] = tmp[0]**`

sourcefile.txt looks like this:
1    (data and numbers)
2    (data and numbers)
3    (data and numbers)
4    (data and numbers)

If anyone can help I would appreciate it a lot.

*Edit* forgot to mention I am using python in the title

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there's a problem reading the file and file.readLines() is returning an empty set, making text an empty string.  It would follow that the split() results in an array of length 0, making even index=0 out or range.

Comment: I added a "print text" line right after file.close() and commented out the rest and it prints out the contents of the file. Could it still be having a problem reading the file if it can print text?